# Selective package updates through apt-get

Tags: 12.04, package-management, xen

I'd like to install a newer package (xen-tools) from Quantal via `apt-get`.

The package is called `xen-tools`.  It doesn't contain any compiled sources.

I need it on Precise because you cannot use `xen-create-image` with the `--dist=precise` option. Why? because there is not option for Precise. Creating a symbolic link doesn't fix it. I've tried patching the `xen-create-image` script manually but it's not creating a working bootable VM unfortunately.

What is the best way of achieving this without pulling in everything but `xen-tools` from Quantal?  As far as I know it doesn't contain any dependencies or sources.

**Note:** I have tried [PinningHowto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto), but  `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01ubuntu` is missing and I can't see where you set the default.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you were on the right track with pinning. I'm not sure if you need to be concerned about `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01ubuntu`. However, you should just be able to create it yourself if you really do need it. The `apt.conf.d` directory just gives you a place that you can add custom configuration directives.

You will probably be fine just following the steps for updating `/etc/apt/sources.list` and adding your package pinning information to a file in `/etc/apt/preferences.d/99-file-name-of-your-choice`. I think that adding the default release was just a precaution.